# Permission denied while installing minikube

Tags: linux, kubernetes, minikube

I was trying to install minikube in WSL2 using /[minikube install](https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2021/11/install-minikube-in-wsl-2-with-kubectl-and-helm/)

In between the installation failed at the below step and got a permission denied error

```
 minikube config set driver docker
 -bash: /usr/local/bin/minikube: Permission denied
```

Tried to gave owner permssion to the user using chown, but still I got the same error

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution to this issue by running the chmod command as given below

```
SP0T3:/usr/local/bin$ chmod +x minikube
SP0T3:/usr/local/bin$ 
minikube config set driver docker
enter code here

❗    These changes will take effect upon a minikube delete and then a minikube start
```